# A basic question on factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Is the following true? If not, can anyone add some reasonable assumptions to make it true?

**Statement.** Let $E/F$ be a field extension and let $\alpha \in E \setminus F$ be algebraic over $F$. If $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then $f(x/\alpha) \in F[\alpha][x]$ is irreducible.

*Attempt to prove the statement.* Suppose for contradiction that $f(x/\alpha) = p(x)q(x)$ where $p(x), q(x) \in (F[\alpha])[x]$ and $\deg(p(x)), \deg(q(x)) > 0$. Over a splitting field $K$ that contains $\alpha$, we can write $f(x) = a(x - r_{1}) \cdots (x - r_{n})$ for some $a \in F^{*}$, so we have

$f(x/\alpha) = (a/\alpha^{n})(x - \alpha r_{1}) \cdots (x - \alpha r_{n})$.

Without loss of generality, we can write $p(x) = \gamma(x - \alpha r_{1}) \cdots (x - \alpha r_{j})$ and $q(x) = \delta(x - \alpha r_{j+1}) \cdots (x - \alpha r_{n})$ for some $\gamma, \delta \in F[\alpha]$ such that $\gamma\delta = a / \alpha^{n}$. Since $p(x), q(x) \in (F[\alpha])[x]$, we have

$p_{0}(x) := \delta p(x) = a(x/\alpha - r_{1}) \cdots (x/\alpha - r_{j}) \in (F[\alpha])[x];$
$q_{0}(x) := (\gamma/a) q(x) = (x/\alpha - r_{j+1}) \cdots (x/\alpha - r_{n}) \in (F[\alpha])[x].$

We have $f(x) = p_{0}(\alpha x)q_{0}(\alpha x)$, and I was wishing that $p_{0}(\alpha x), q_{0}(\alpha x)$ were polynomials over $F$, but there are no reasons to believe so.

**Motivation.** The motivation was to show $\Phi_{p}(x/\alpha) \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha][x]$ is irreducible where $\alpha := 2^{1/p}$ and $\Phi_{p}(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the $p$th cyclotomic polynomial where $p$ is a prime number. I did attempt this in a different way but I am not sure how to conclude whether this is true.

*A connection to the statement.* Write $\zeta := e^{2\pi i/p}$, and we have $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta, \alpha]$ as a splitting field of $x^{p} - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $(p-1)p$, which shows that $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha\zeta, \alpha] : \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]] = p-1$, thus $\alpha \zeta$ must have the minimal polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha][x]$ whose degree is $p-1$.

If the previous statement is true, there is no choice but $g(x) = \alpha^{p}\Phi_{p}(x/\alpha)$, but like I said, I am not sure.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^2-2$, irreducible over the rationals; is $f(x/\sqrt2)$ irreducible?

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was too much of an assumption. But what about $\Phi_{p}(x/2^{1/p})$? Is it irreducible if we adjoin $2^{1/p}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$? If so, can we extract some reasonable assumptions from this to refine the statement?

Comment: I think you have proved (in the paragraph starting, *A connection to the statement*) that $\Phi_p(x/2^{1/p})$ is irreducible over ${\bf Q}(2^{1/p})$.

Comment: I can see that there is an irreducible polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[2^{1/p}][x]$ with degree $p-1$ that takes a root of $\Phi_{p}(x/2^{1/p})$. But there might be more than one such $g(x)$.

Comment: If two irreducible polynomials share a root, then each is a constant multiple of the other.

Comment: Yes, but $\Phi_{p}(x/2^{1/p})$ can have two distinct roots $r_{1}, r_{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[2^{1/p}]$ whose minimal polynomials are $g_{1}(x), g_{2}(x)$, coprime over the same simple extension. We still do not know $\Phi_{p}(x/2^{1/p})$ is irreducible over this extension, or at least I don't think what I wrote is enough.

Comment: The roots of $\Phi_p(x/2^{1/p})$ are the numbers $2^{1/p}\zeta$, where $\zeta$ runs through the nonreal $p$th roots of unity. They aren't in ${\bf Q}(2^{1/p})$.

Comment: The polynomial $(x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 2)$ is reducible, but it does not take any root in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/p})$. But notice that $x^{2} + 1$ and $x^{2} + 2$ are irreducible and they take roots of this polynomial. How can we make sure that something like this does not happen at all?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "they take roots of this polynomial," as I don't know which polynomial you mean by "this polynomial". The only polynomial we have been discussing is $\Phi_p(x/2^{1/p})$, and surely $x^2+1$ does not have among its roots any roots of *that* polynomial.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say "roots of $f_{1}(x) = x^{2} + 1$ and $f_{2}(x) = x^{2} + 2$ are roots of $f(x) = (x^{2} + 1)(x^{2} + 2)$." In this example, $f_{1}, f_{2}$ are the minimal polynomials of the roots of $f$ but $f$ is not irreducible. Of course, $f$ is not $\Phi_{p}(x/2^{1/p})$ and this is quite not the same case, and I admit that $f$ is a bad example to express my concern.

I know any root of $\Phi_{p}(x/2^{1/p})$ has degree $p-1$ minimal polynomial but what if $\Phi_{p}(x/2^{1/p})$ is reducible? Why would that be a contradiction?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of an algebraic number $\alpha$ has these properties: it is irreducible, and it divides any other polynomial vanishing at $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ has degree $p-1$ minimal polynomial, and $\Phi_p$ (which is of degree $p-1$) vanishes at $\alpha$, then $\Phi_p$ must be the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, so it must be irreducible.

Comment: I see. So asking whether a polynomial is irreducible can be answered by degree of simple extension of its root (whichever root we choose)! Thanks for your patience Gerry Myerson.

Comment: So, if you understand how it works now, you can write it up as an answer to the question. After a while, you can accept your answer.

Comment: I definitely will. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little regretful that I have not thought about this much before I asked this question. After talking to Gerry Myerson, I realized that the statement that I stated was very far from being true. Instead, we have the following.

**Lemma.** A polynomial $f \in F[x]$ is irreducible if and only if it is a minimal polynomial of some $\alpha$ in some extension $E/F$.

*Proof.* Suppose $f$ is irreducible. Then take $E = F[x]/(f)$. The converse is trivial. Q.E.D.

This seems like a very naive lemma, but I think the following variation looked very nontrivial to me before.

**Corollary.** A polynomial $f \in F[x]$ is irreducible if and only if there exists an extension $E/F$ and $\alpha \in E$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$ and $\deg(f) = [E:F]$.

*Proof.* If we have an extension $E/F$ and $\alpha \in E$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ must divide $f$ since it is the generator of the kernel of evaluation $(F[x], x) \rightarrow (F[\alpha], \alpha)$. The rest follows from Lemma. Q.E.D.

My previous question was as follows.

**Question.** Let $\alpha \in E$ is algebraic over $F$ where $E/F$ is an extension. How can we tell $f(x/\alpha)$ is irreducible over $F[\alpha]$ given $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$?

**Answer.** By Corollary, the polynomial $f(x/\alpha)$ is irreducible over $F[\alpha]$ if and only if we have an extension $L/F[\alpha]$ and $\beta \in L$ such that $f(\beta/\alpha) = 0$ and $\deg(f) = [L:F[\alpha]]$.

Comment: The order in which you introduce things in writing matters. In the lemma and corollary you should not mention $E$ before you mention $f$, otherwise it seems like $E$ does not depend on $f$ (you said $E$ can be any field extension before you mentioned $f$ at all). Is the $E$ in your **question** and **answer** supposed to be one and the same field? If $f(\beta/\alpha)=0$ for some $\beta\in E$ then it's still possible for $f$ to be reducible over $F[\alpha]$. Perhaps you mean $\beta\in L/F[\alpha]$, and $\deg(f)=[L:F[\alpha]]$ for some extension $L/F[\alpha]$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I forgot to erase extension before mentioning $f$, and also you are right about question & answer. Thanks for pointing those out.

Comment: I fixed the misleading order.